# how to fix the while loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
function div(num) {
  while (num <= 9) {
    var a = (num - (num % 10));
    var b = (a / 10)
    var c = 0
    var digits = num.toString().split("")
    for (i = digits.length - 1; i > 2; i--) {
      c = digits[i]
    }
    num = b - (c * 2);
  }

  return num;
}
document.write(div(1234))
```

My code is supposed  to take the number and get the last digit and subtract it from the rest of the number, and repeat the process until the answer is lesser or equal to 9. I made a while loop but I keep on getting the number I started with. What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Edit :

It is supposed to multiply the last digit by 2 and then subtract it from the rest of the number and then repeat the process until the answer is less than or equal to 9

Comment: edit : it is supposed to multiply the last digit by 2 and then subtract it from the rest of the number and then repeat the process until the answer is less than or equal to 9

Comment: Please add the edit comment that you just made back into your question.  You can (and should) click the 'edit' button right above the comments section to make edits.  You're encouraged to make edits to improve your question.

Comment: Put up an example input & output.

Comment: Learn to help yourself by learning how to debug JavaScript: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/?hl=en .

Answer (score 2):

```
while (num<=9)
```

This should be

```
while (num>=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the `while` loop will be executed only for a number that is less than 9.

Use `while(num >= 9)` instead of `while(num <= 9)`.

```js
function div(num) {
  while (num >= 9) {
    var a = (num - (num % 10));
    var b = (a / 10)
    var c = 0
    var digits = num.toString().split("")
    for (i = digits.length - 1; i > 2; i--) {
      c = digits[i]
    }
    num = b - (c * 2);
  }

  return num;
}
document.write(div(1234));
```